# Linking multiple projects together using a single console application C#

Tags: c#, webapi

Background:
I'm trying to create a C# WebAPI, a Blazor frontend and a console project that are all all started by a single console application (which is separate from those shown above). I'll refer to the controlling project as the master project. All the projects are .NET 6
I'm starting with webAPI part and have created a standard "WeatherController" template web API. I have then changed it to a class rather than a console application and try to run it from my master project, I cannot access the web API and checking the ports that are listening on the computer show that it is not listening on the ports in the appsettings.json.

Here is the code for the master project:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Run(args);
    }

    private static async Task Run(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Startup webAPI = new Startup();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And the code for the web api project:

```
public class Startup
{
    WebApplication app;

    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        // Add services to the container
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }
        app.MapGet("/welcome", () =>
        {
            var con = "<html><body><h1>Hello!</h1><p> <h3>  API Is Ready To Work!!! </h3> </p></body></html>";

            return Results.Content(con, "text/html");
        });
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

I'm sure its something simple that I'm missing, but I'm unsure as to what it is!

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is wanting to startup several projects, then right click on your solution (in solution explorer), select properties, then 'multiple startup projects' and set the action of the projects you want to start to 'start'.

Then, when you press >Start (or F5 or however you run your project), it will start everything you selected.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, that would allow all the projects to start at once, but wouldn't it be difficult to control the different projects say if one crashes?

Comment: You need to try it to see if it works for you.  It has worked for me for many years.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go. Is it easy to 'deploy' as a single package this way?